# No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a test method. AND I am not even calling the Batch in that method?

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, exception

I am getting this Error while deploying code to live:

> System.UnexpectedException: No more than one executeBatch can be
>   called from within a test method. Please make sure the iterable
>   returned from your start method matches the batch size, resulting in
>   one executeBatch invocation.  Stack Trace: External entry point

I am getting about 26 of these messages, each for different method. In any of these test methods, `executeBatch` method is not called.

I have batch classes but all are scheduled to execute on specific time. These batch classes are never initiated in other classes or triggers.

Where should I look to debug this?

Comment: Look through your triggers to see which ones execute a batch, then see if you perform any of those dml operations.

Comment: @AdrianLarson none of the the triggers executes a batch, that is what bothers me. In one of the test method I am just inserting an Account record, and in account trigger I have no `executeBatch`, and it still gives this error.

Comment: do you have in the testmethods (or their downstream classes) calls to a queueable or schedulable that in turn is doing an executeBatch?

Comment: Considering `Stack Trace: External entry point`, you might want to investigate if any installed packages are the cause. If you have any, try uninstalling them one at a time.